# Rich Text Field in SharePoint List Infopath form 2010

Tags: infopath

I am facing an issue with Rich Text Field in SharePoint List Infopath form 2010 , I have replaced a default Custom List form with Infopath Form 2010 and now I am not able to see "Upload File" option in the ribbon control under Insert tag when I place cursor over the Rich Text field whereas I was able to upload file in default form of SharePoint List.

I think the reason why is that when the form is published from Infopath it overrides the ribbon on the form.  Is there a way to get the ribbon to be the one from the default sharepoint form instead?

Thanks for helping me out..